# Best way to monitor changes in filesystem in a server

Tags: filesystems, monitoring

Recently I have an attack to one of my servers. Apart from harden the security measures at place, I am planning to install a tool to monitor changes in the filesystem.

I want a free tool (no cost) and want it to send reports via email or save the results remotely to avoid manipulation.

I've been check fam and I think it could do the job. However I wanted to know if there are other solutions out there.

Comment: What Distribution are you using? I know some have the ability to install an audit package that is part of the base OS, just not installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a CentOS / RHEL based system, you can install `audit.x86_64` and configure the default auditing system for the server for commands, files, what ever you are looking to audit. There is a how to for Cent OS below and I also linked the RHEL site but it may require an account. I am not familiar with Debian based systems or Ubuntu so it could be the same commands with a similar package. A quick google search also finds something for Ubuntu pretty quick.

**RHEL/CentOS:**
[CentOS 7 How To Use the Linux Auditing System](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7) 
[RHEL 7 System Auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) 
[RHEL 6 System Auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing)

After looking into it a bit more, the same auditctl system seems to be able to be installed on Ubunutu as RHEL 7.

**Ubuntu:** 
the command below will install it on Ubuntu. the man pages should explain how it works though I am fairly sure its almost the same as the RPM installed version.
    `sudo apt-get install auditd`

Comment: My distribution is Ubuntu 16 server

Answer (score 1):

`tripwire` is getting a bit long in the tooth, but still works well and does the job it supposed to (send you emails warning of any and all changes to monitored files - e.g. set it to monitor all files by default and exclude files/dirs you don't care about).

Available pre-packaged for most, if not all linux distros (as well as *bsd).  Here's the description from the debian tripwire package:

```
Package: tripwire
Description-en: file and directory integrity checker
 Tripwire is a tool that aids system administrators and users in
 monitoring a designated set of files for any changes.  Used with
 system files on a regular (e.g., daily) basis, Tripwire can notify
 system administrators of corrupted or tampered files, so damage
 control measures can be taken in a timely manner.

Homepage: https://github.com/Tripwire/tripwire-open-source
```

I also recommend using `git` for version control of all important files (and `git push` to push changes to a remote repository as a backup to protect against corruption and accidental or deliberate deletion).

And, of course, `etckeeper` for automating revision control (`git` by default) on `/etc`:

```
Package: etckeeper
Description-en: store /etc in git, mercurial, bzr or darcs
 The etckeeper program is a tool to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial,
 bzr or darcs repository. It hooks into APT to automatically commit changes
 made to /etc during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata that version
 control systems do not normally support, but that is important for /etc, such
 as the permissions of /etc/shadow. It's quite modular and configurable, while
 also being simple to use if you understand the basics of working with version
 control.

Homepage: https://etckeeper.branchable.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AIDE is a tool for monitoring file system changes. It can be used
to detect unauthorized monitored files and directories. AIDE was
written to be a simple and free alternative to Tripwire. Features
currently included in AIDE are as follows:

    o  File attributes monitored: permissions, inode, user, group
       file size, mtime, atime, ctime, links and growing size.
    o  Checksums and hashes supported: SHA1, MD5, RMD160, and TIGER.
       CRC32, HAVAL and GOST if Mhash support is compiled in.
    o  Plain text configuration files and database for simplicity.
    o  Rules, variables and macros that can be customized to local
       site or system policies.
    o  Powerful regular expression support to selectively include or
       exclude files and directories to be monitored.
    o  gzip database compression if zlib support is compiled in.
    o  Free software licensed under the GNU General Public License.

The homepage of AIDE is https://aide.github.io
```